# Import cards without knowing set in mtggoldfish

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I want to use the "my price" feature in mtggoldfish, so I need to import my collection. I have my collection in a spreadsheed, but I don't have the set names for each card, and for the purposes of "my price" feature I shouldn't really need them so I don't want to go through and do all the data entry to list them. Is there any way to import as "unknown set" or "set not listed" or anything like that?

Comment: Have you considered contacting the site and seeing if they can provide you with the information you need? https://www.mtggoldfish.com/contact

Comment: Yes, I also contacted them. If they get back to me, I'll add the answer here. But maybe someone already knows the answers and sees this before the site admins do.